# How the content of XML files can be used in QnA Maker?

Tags: xml, azure, azure-qna-maker

QnA Maker automatically extracts question-answer pairs from various data sources like PDF, DOC, Excel etc. Is it possible in QnA Maker to extract the content of XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible to ingest `xml` file directly as of today. But you can try to manually transform & feed it in expected formats.

> What format does the tool expect for the file content?
>
> The tool
> supports the following file formats for ingestion:
>
> - .tsv: QnA
>   contained in the format Question(tab)Answer.
> - .txt, .docx, .pdf: QnA
>   contained as regular FAQ content--that is, a sequence of questions and
>   answers.

[Reference](https://www.qnamaker.ai/old/Documentation/Faqs)